# Where should I store images which I want to keep on MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql

I am designing a table in which I need images to get stored for every row. Should I upload the images to a folder on google-drive and then store the shareable link or should I store the images locally in a folder ? If stored locally , what address should I store in the Table ?

Comment: Web Project or desktop project?

Comment: Size of the images? Expected concurrency? Have you tried those options? Have you had any problem with them? Errors?

Comment: Its a college level mini project where I just have to show a prototype . The image size will be less than 1 MB . I haven' tried anything yet . I just wanted to know which method is faster and better.

Comment: Storing in MySQL is more complicated than necessary. It's simpler to store elsewhere and have a link.

Comment: File system storage, and put URLs (or fragments of URLs) in your table rows. Otherwise you have to figure out how to retrieve and deliver BLOBs from database to user. It's over-the-top hard to get right for an expert, and guaranteed to drive a beginner bonkers.